# Any() not giving what I would expect

Tags: c#, linq

delMo is a list of DateTime. I have it populated with 3/1/2014 and 4/1/2014. **The results I get back is 2 records (what I expected) but the p.dt values for both records show 3/1/2014. I would expect 1 record to be 3/1/2014 and the other to be 4/1/2014.**

My understanding of using Any() in this way is like using an in() statement in SQL. However, the results I get back don't seem to reflect this. Any ideas on what I did wrong here?

```
var result = (from p in db.Table1
             where (from dt in delMo
                    where p.dt == dt).Any()
                   &&
                   (from s in db.Stores
                    where p.storeID == s.ID).Any()
             select p).ToList();
```

[EDIT]
I broke the problem down further and am getting very strange results. I hardcoded the store ID to 5 and it still gives me the problem. I even loop through delMo and pass in the 1 value to p.dt and on the first pass of 3/1/2014 I get the expected result. The second pass uses 4/1/2014 and it returns 3/1/2014!! If I only have 4/1/2014 in delMo then it works. It's like it's keeping the first 3/1/2014 record for some reason. It makes no sense.

Comment: How did you initialize `dt` and what is the exact value of `p.dt`, there may be `Time` part which is different.

Comment: `Any` is not like `IN`, it is like `EXISTS` in SQL.

Comment: @Selman22 Is there an In like functionality then? I need Table1 to return back the records where the dates are in delMo. My understanding is this is how you'd do that.

Comment: Your query will return rows from `Table1` which meets the  following criteria: the record date within the March and its storeid exists in stores. Is this your intention?

Comment: I want records from table1 that = 3/1/2014 AND 4/1/2014 exactly, since delMo list has both. It's not like a between, but an exact match of those dates. So it looks like .Any() returns true and tells me Table1 contains 3/1/2014 and 4/1/2014 but it doesn't seem like it actually returns me those records. instead it's returning 2 records that are both 3/1/2014.

Comment: then one of your id's doesn't match with any record in the `Stores` table. if you want `IN` clause you can easily change first any to `delMo.Contains(p.dt)` but I don't believe it makes any difference.problem is in your second condition.

Comment: The stores id part works fine on it's own and I see both 3/1/2014 and 4/1/2014 in the results. It's only when I add the delMo part that the results I get back are the right number of records but the values aren't right.

Comment: This still isn't working. The solutions below are still returning 3 records both with 3/1/2014 even when I hardcode the store id value. Writing SQL against this where I have an in() for the dates gives me the correct results. How does linq handle this?

Answer (score 1):

`Any` returns a `bool` indicating whether or not any elements in the collection satisfy a given condition. When used without a predicate, it indicates whether or not the collection contains elements. I'm not sure if that's what you meant by saying

> in this way is like using in an in() statement

but that's what it does. [See this link for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As to your question in the comments, I believe something like this should do it. I'm not a huge fan of using `linq` over the `IEnumerable` extensions, so bear with me.

```
var result = db.Table1.Where( p =>
                delMo.Contains( p.dt ) &&
                db.Stores.Where( s=> s.ID == p.storeId ) );
```

This will return the values from `db.Table1` where `p.dt` is in `delMo` and `p.storeId` is in `db.Stores`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Any ideas on how I could change what I have to make Table1 return the right records where the dates are from the delMo list of dates?

Comment: instead of `delMo.Where( e => e == p.dt).Any()` why don't you just do this: `delMo.Contains(p.dt)` and by the way, your solution doesn't make any difference except you are using extension method syntax.

Comment: `Stores.Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, I guess you want to replace it with `Any` there.

Answer (score 0):

This should help. I wonder if `P` has a Stores collection, if it has, then it is more straightforward, but I'm not making assumptions.

```
(from p in db.Table1
  where delMo.Contains(p.dt)
        && db.Stores.Any(x=>x.ID==p.storeID)
  select p).ToList();
```

Note: Date should be exact match(including time) for this to work.

Comment: So I'm getting the same bad result but here is a question. Since delMo has 2 items (3/1/2014 and 4/1/2014) why would I get back 2 records both with p.dt of 3/1/2014? What is the reason for that happening? Let's say I narrow this down and write SQL like: select * from Tabl1 where storeID = 5 and dt in ('03/01/2014', '04/01/2014'), I get my expected result. If I do (from p in db.Table1 where p.storeID = 5 && delMo.Contains(pd.dt) select p).ToList(), I get 2 records and both DT's are 3/1/2014

Comment: Woah, even if I loop over the delMo and pass in 1 at a time I get 3/1/2014 when I pass in just 4/1/2014. This is so strange. Is something not getting cleared out or something? This makes no sense. If I just use 4/1/2014 then I get 4/1/2014. It's like if I run the same query twice it keeps returning the first date used. So confused now. Is this the entity framework doing something strange here?